# Swift Int array to MetalBuffer<Int>

Tags: arrays, swift, integer, metal, metalkit

I'm studying app development with swift and metal kit

I want to convert an int type array to Metalbuffer, because I have to cover that array data in Shader.h

Before operating the shader.h, the array's values have not problems.
But, in and after the shader.h, the buffer's that converted from array have some problems.

for example, I send [1, 2, 3, 4] to Metalbuffer and I call the `renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(Metalbuffer)`.
then, In the Shader.h it appears like [1, 0, 2, 0]
what's the problem???

this is my sample code

```
var int_array = Array(reapeating: 1, count: 100)

init(){
    Buffers = MetalBuffer<Int>(device: device, array: int_array, index: kBuffers.rawValue, options: [])
    
}
 
func updateIntArray(){
    for i in 0..<100 {
        int_array[i] = i % 20
    }
    Buffers = MetalBuffer<Int>(device: device, array: int_array, index: kBuffers.rawValue, options: [])
    
    (other codes about rendering)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(Buffers)
}
```

the `updateIntArray` is called per every frame by view controller.
I printed the sizeof(Buffers[i]) after the shader call, it was 4!

How can I preserve the data without being inserted with 0?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no `MetalBuffer` in `Metal` module. You need to show us more sources for this question to make sense, because it doesn't make any sense without at least sources for `MetalBuffer` and `renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer` extension that takes that metal buffer.

Comment: We also need to see the code for kBuffers.

Comment: Oh, the `MetalBuffer` is a struct for utility and now I replace it with `MTLBuffer`.
Also, `redderEncoder` is initialized with `commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: )`

And, the kBuffers was set previously as some Integer number in the `ShaderTypes.h`!

Thanks to your kind attention, I was able to solve it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of code missing from your question, but I will show you how I pass an array as a parameter to my fragment shader.

I have a ShaderTypes.h file to create a custom value type that can be used with both Swift and MSL (Metal Shading Language). You will need a bridging header for this if you want to use it on the Swift side.

```
#ifndef ShaderTypes_h
#define ShaderTypes_h
#include <simd/simd.h>

typedef struct {
    float intensity;
    float time;
    float width;
    float height;
    float originX;
    float originY;
}KeyPointValues;
```

My goal is to pass an array of KeyPointValues as a parameter to my fragment shader. On the swift side I do something like this:

```
var keyPoints = [KeyPointValues()]

for index in 0...10 {
   keyPoints.append(KeyPointValues())
}

var count = keyPoints.count

guard let keyPointBuffer = context.device.makeBuffer(bytes: keyPoints, length: MemoryLayout<KeyPointValues>.stride * count) else { return }

commandEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(keyPointBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&count, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: count), index: 1)
```

You need to pass in count as well because there is no `keyPoints.count` counterpart in MSL.

Then the fragment shader looks something like this:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <simd/simd.h>
#import "ShaderTypes.h"

using namespace metal;

fragment half4 rosyFilter(device const KeyPointValues *keyPoints [[buffer(0)]],
                          constant uint &count [[ buffer(1) ]]
                          ) {

   for(uint index = 0; index < count; index++) {
      float intensity = keyPoints[index].intensity;
   }
}
```

Hopefully this can get you started in the right direction. You are using an array of Int, so it should be easier as there is probably no need to define a custom struct to use between Swift and MSL.

I am also somewhat new to Metal so I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing things. I appreciate any feedback from people with more experience.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot!
Actually, just transferring Int array to Shader.h has still problem that I've been saying. It passes the buffer which consists of [1, 0, 2, 0]. 

So, I create a struct which has only int attribute.

```
#ifndef ShaderTypes_h
#define ShaderTypes_h

#include <simd/simd.h>

typedef struct {
    int rawval;
}IntRaw;
```

In this trial, your answer was very helpful!
Finally, I made it that I want!

I appreciate your kind help

Comment: That helped me a lot to get a for loop off the ground thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you think an *Int* in Swift is an *int* in MSL. Actually
*Int* = *long* and
*Int32* = *int*
So either send in an *Int32* or read your input as *long*